# Search partial names from a column against a List in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the names in a list called `search_list` which i need to lookup at the `Server Name` column, i though using `isin()` function would be easy to match against list but it only match absolute names only. So, if there are names like `kpc1148` as `kpc1148.db.com` then it will not print.

While `astype(str).str.contains("kpc4440")` works fine but it's not taking the List `search_list` with this, i can do that using for loop if no options.

If there is any other option to match partial names then that will be helpful.

```
import pandas as pd
# server names to be searched on the file in list format

search_list =  ["kpc1148","kpc1156","kpc1158","kpc1165"]
# sorted column list
cols = [ 'Server', 'Server Name', 'iLO FW', 'Firmware', 'Appliance Name']

df = pd.read_csv("Server-Inventory.csv", usecols=cols)
df = df[df['Server Name'].isin(search_list)]

# df = df[df['Server Name'].astype(str).str.contains("kpc4440")]

print(df)
```

### Result:

```
               Server Server Name            iLO FW                Firmware         Appliance Name
440   ENC2002, bay 10     kpc2021  2.55 Aug 16 2017  I36 v2.52 (10/25/2020)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
981    enc8023, bay 7     kpc8291  2.55 Aug 16 2017  I36 v2.52 (10/25/2020)  OV C7000 enclosures 2
2642  enc8009, bay 12     kpc8472  1.30 May 31 2018  I42 v1.42 (06/20/2020)                 ov7003
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the list like this:

```
df[df['Server Name'].str.contains('|'.join(search_list))]
```